# What is the meaning of "reclaimation of storage" with respect to threads' pthread_join() & pthread_detach()?

Tags: c, multithreading, memory-leaks, valgrind

I wrote a simple thread program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define THREADS     5

void* HelloWorld(void *t) 
{
    printf("Thread ID #%lu: (%lu) Hello World !!\n", pthread_self(), (unsigned long)t);         

    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t thread[THREADS];
    uint32_t i;
    int err;

    for(i = 0; i < THREADS; ++i)
    {   
        err = pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, &HelloWorld, (void*)(unsigned long long)i);
        if(err != 0)
        {   
            printf("Error %d: Thread %d Creation Unsuccessful !!\n", err, i); 
        }   
        printf("Thread %lu in main()\n", pthread_self());
    }   
/*
    for(i = 0; i < THREADS; ++i)
    {
        pthread_join(thread[i], NULL);  // Error checking implemented
    }
*/
    return 0;
}
```

But on using **valgrind** as:

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes ./hello
```

It shows same output for memory usage/leaks whether `pthread_join()` is used or not used in the program.

Please explain this behaviour as I read [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_join.html) that:

> > The pthread_join() or pthread_detach() function should eventually be called for every thread that is created with the detachstate attribute set to PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE so that storage associated with the thread may be reclaimed.

How the storage is reclaimed if I do not call `pthread_join()`

Comment: I can not reproduce any leaks if the threads are joined. I tested this on a recent Debian Stable.

Comment: @alk: So anyways, I should use `pthread_join()`, right!!

Comment: Yes, `pthread_join()` shall be called for each thread, for which the thread's detached state had not been explicitly set to `PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED` either via `pthread_attr_setdetachstate()` or by calling `pthread_detach()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two questions raised from what I understand. One is why `valgrind` reports the same memory leaks with or without calls to `pthread_join()`, and the other is how does calling `pthread_join()` reclaim storage if it is not actually freeing any memory.

One possible explanation for both issues is that your thread library does not actually free any memory after a call to `pthread_join()`, but instead places the resources that were allocated into a "available if I end up creating another thread in the future" container. Lets call that container a pool. The next call to `pthread_create()` can re-use any resources that are in the pool. If the pool is empty, new memory is allocated.

Without calling `pthread_join()`, any resources associated with the exited thread would not be returned to the pool. Thus, those resources would remain unusable, the pool remain empty, and so a new `pthread_create()` would allocate more resources for the thread creation request.

This means a `pthread_join()` does not necessarily free any memory at all. It can be simply placing the reaped resources into a pool maintained by the thread library. So, with or without calls to `pthread_join()`, `valgrind` would show the same amount of "leaked" memory. But, the memory is reclaimed by `pthread_join()`, since it is placed in a pool for a future call to `pthread_create()`.

Comment: But I have done `pthread_join` on separate loop after `pthread_create`

Comment: @nishant: You asked why memory shows same leaks with and without `pthread_join()`.

Comment: I am sorry, but I didn't understand your answer, please explain more.

Comment: Okay, I expanded the answer.

Comment: Okay! quick summary of what I understood: Memory will **always** be allocated for `pthread_create` call, but if I use `pthread_join`, the pre-allocated resources can also be used by new threads, which will be unusable otherwise.